# jQuery - Select table row where all children (images) have no "sel" class

Tags: jquery

I need to change the class of a TR when all the child images in that TR have no "sel" class applied to them (this class can be affected by other things on the page).

How do I do this?

Comment: need to see your html,  have you even attempted? if so, your attempt would be benificial to you recieving any answers.

Comment: Yes I've attempted, been at it a couple of hours trying to figure out. I thought it was pretty straightforward waht I was asking which is why I didn't include my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return all <tr>'s that don't have any img.sel's in them

```
$('tr').filter( function() {
  return $(this).find('img.sel').length == 0;
})
.addClass('poopiepants');
```

You can then chain anything onto that that you need, like changing the class.

**UPDATED TO SHOW CHAINING**

Comment: Thanks Groovetrain. This is the last thing I was looking at before I decided to ask the question. I'm not 100% sure though, on where to add code to do something to that?

Comment: Can I then mess with $(this) after return?

Comment: You could fire it off whenever you needed to add the class or un-add the class.  If you're dealing with a HUGE table, it may be better to only use it on a specific row, specifically on a row that just had the 'sel' class added/removed from of one of its child images.

Comment: @Mark well that's the beauty of jQuery.  You can just chain it.  I've edited my answer to show you.

Comment: @Mark Does this answer your question?  Or do you need more clarification.  Can you mark it as answered if so?  Thx

Comment: Wow...this really is some powerful stuff. Thanks Groove :)

Comment: It does answer my question, but it still isn't working - I've never used function within the code like that before though (yes I'm a newb) so I'm going to look into getting it working myself :) thanks.

Comment: @Mark word.  Good luck on your journey man, it wasn't long ago when I was in the same boat you are!

Answer (score 0):

It can all be done in the selector:

`tr:not([class=sel])`

Comment: I don't think this is really answering his question... He needs to get all of the tr's that have no child images with the 'sel' class.  But yes, you're right, that would get all of the tr's that don't have the 'sel' class.